# How to add new object to method, which retrieves data from MySQL db in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Need your advice very much, I'm new here and may be asking in wrong way! Look - I can declare arrayList with parameters:

```
List<Values> list= new ArrayList<>();
```

Then with these methods I add new object to list and save it in list and database (like on pic). All works well, but (Main question) how to connect all it with method which retreives data from MySQL database - to be able both: retrieve from DB & add new entries (I attach this method below):

[image]

```
public void addNewUser(){    
    Values newValue = new Values();//new object of model class
    newValue.setEditable(true);//open rendered input fields on xhtml page
    list.add(newValue);
    }

public void saveNewUser(){
    for(Values value: list){
        addUser();//insert data to DB
        value.setEditable(false);//close rendered input fields on xhtml page
    }
}
```

My method, which retrieves data from DB:

```
public ArrayList<Values> getAllUsers(){
        ArrayList<Values> usersList= new ArrayList<>();
        SQL= "SELECT id,orderNo,productName,price,qty FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
        databaseConnection();
        try {
            prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
            boolean found= false;
            while (resultSet.next()== true) {
                Values allValues= new Values();
                  allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                  allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
                  allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
                  allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
                  allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
                  usersList.add(allValues);
                  found= true;
            }
              resultSet.close();
              prepStatement.close();
              if (found) {
                return usersList;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in getAllUsers()-->"+e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            close(connection);
        }
        return (null);
    }
```

Comment: what wrong with this code?

Comment: No need to check while (resultSet.next()== true) its also work like while(resultSet.next())

Comment: Code works, but separately: I can or retreive or add data,- I want to know how to connect all it with method which retreives data from mysql database - to be able both: retreive from DB & add new entries